# Chequear atributos archivo XML obtenidos de Excel

Tags: excel, xml, comparaciones, atributos

Tengo un archivo de configuración del controlador lógico programable que se parece a esto:

```
<ConfigurationFile_Extended Features="PCOnlyUpdate">
  <ConfigurationFile ModuleTypeCode="32841" ModuleMajorVersion="7" ModuleMinorVersion="3">
    <Header>
      <Description>7320 Configuration file</Description>
      <Saved_on ConfigSuite_Version="3.105.1.0">17-Jan-23 09:22:21</Saved_on>
    </Header>
    <PC_Header>
      <UpdateVersion>0</UpdateVersion>
    </PC_Header>
    <Alarms>
      <Digital_Inputs>
        <Digital_Input_1>
          <Function Comment="Pressure Switch">21</Function>
          <Action Comment="None">0</Action>
          <Arming Comment="Always">1</Arming>
          <Type Comment="Close to Activate">0</Type>
          <Timer Comment="0s">0</Timer>
          <Trip Comment="0">0</Trip>
          <Return Comment="0">0</Return>
        </Digital_Input_1>
        <Digital_Input_2>
          <Function Comment="Oil Switch">22</Function>
          <Action Comment="None">0</Action>
          <Arming Comment="Always">1</Arming>
          <Type Comment="Close to Activate">0</Type>
          <Timer Comment="0s">0</Timer>
          <Trip Comment="0">0</Trip>
          <Return Comment="0">0</Return>
        </Digital_Input_2>
        <Digital_Input_3>
          <Function Comment="User Configured">0</Function>
          <Action Comment="Electrical Trip">2</Action>
          <Arming Comment="From Safety On">3</Arming>
          <Type Comment="Close to Activate">0</Type>
          <Timer Comment="0s">0</Timer>
          <Trip Comment="0">0</Trip>
          <Return Comment="0">0</Return>
        </Digital_Input_3>
        <Digital_Input_4>
          <Function Comment="User Configured">0</Function>
          <Action Comment="Warning">5</Action>
          <Arming Comment="Never">0</Arming>
          <Type Comment="Close to Activate">0</Type>
          <Timer Comment="0s">0</Timer>
          <Trip Comment="0">0</Trip>
          <Return Comment="0">0</Return>
        </Digital_Input_4>

//

    <Timers>
      <Warming Comment="1s">10</Warming>
      <Cooling Comment="1m">600</Cooling>
      <Cooling_time_at_idle Comment="0s">0</Cooling_time_at_idle>
      <Sensor_Fail Comment="2.0s">20</Sensor_Fail>
    </Timers>
```

Me gustaría escribir un programa para comprar/comprobar este archivo xml con un archivo excel.

```
| Column A        | Column B       | Column C | Column D | Column F        |
| Digital input 1 | Pressure Switch| None     | Always   | Close to Active |
| Digital input 2 | Oil Switch     | None     | Always   | Close to Active |
| Digital input 3 | ....
| Digital input 4 | ....
| Digital input 5 | ....

| Digital output 1 | ....
| Digital output 2 | ....
| Digital output 3 | ....
```

También en el archivo excel tengo los valores para Temporizadores

Teniendo en cuenta que soy principiante,

1. Cuál sería el lenguaje más apropiado para hacer esto? y el más fácil?
2. Por dónde debería empezar a aprender/leer?
3. El siguiente paso será escribir esas entradas/salidas digitales y los Temporizadores.
4. El archivo tiene 17128 líneas de código, ¿es esto un problema?

Comment: Buenas, yo con lo que se me decantaría por c#, ya que tiene librerías para leer excel y xml, empezaria por dos funciones una para leer el xml entrante y otra los campos de excel.

Comment: La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros,herramientas,librerías u otros recursos externos
Estas preguntas tienden a recibir respuestas basadas en opiniones